# Plotting a histogram of particle intensity vs pixel

Tags: matlab

I am trying to reproduce a figure, shown below, of a particle intensity binned by the pixel number then fit the distribution to a Gaussian. I have a similarly magnified intensity image of my particle, with 8-bit depth, loaded into MATLAB.

I am having difficulty understanding how the bottom figure seems to retain spatial information after binning. The goal is to fit the distribution to a Gaussian.

[image]

Comment: Can you give the reference, where this figure is from?

Comment: I am not really sure what you are asking; are you wondering how to get the distribution from your image? Perhaps it is not clear to you that the distribution shown is one "slice" through your image on any axis?

Comment: The reference is http://lem.che.udel.edu/sandbox/groups/furstgroupwiki/wiki/7672a/attachments/cf8b1/Handout_particle_tracking.pdf

Comment: @DanBoschen It wasn't clear to me that the plot was a slice. I agree it could be that simple. It's a single slice hist with the bin range from -10 to + 10?

Comment: Yes and single slice histogram through the center of the object with a bin range of -10 to +10 pixels.  I wasn't sure if that was your confusion. The top view of the plot is a 3D Gaussian distribution which looks like a hill, no matter which way you slice it in profile through the center you will get a Gaussian distribution.   So if you slice in the x axis, the y axis or any diagonal new axis that you create, as long as it goes through the center it will be an identical Gaussian distribution.

Comment: Since the image is a sphere, and I assume the x and y axis are similarly scaled, the intensity is formed from two IID (independent and identically distributed) Gauissan RV for the intensity vs position: One for the x axis and one for the y axis resulting in the image that you show.

Comment: @DanBoschen Thank you for that explanation. Knowing this I can easily reproduce this figure with my data.

Comment: Since that was the issue I will add it as an answer below so that we can close out the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The expected distribution of intensity versus x,y position is formed by two idependent and identically distributed gaussian random variables; one for each axis. The distribution shown is for one "slice" through this 2D distribution.  The top view of the distribution can be envisioned as a 3d Gaussian "hill", and the histogram shown is for one slice through this hill as viewed from the side, where the slice can be from any direction as long as it goes through the center (origin).